# Python - Reading from excel without pandas and inserting into Postgre

Tags: python, pandas

Can you please advise on the best technique i can use to read below data into a postgre table using non panda library: The layout of the excel file is rather tricky. The excel file has columns horizontally and vertically. 
[image: image showing data to be written to DB]

How can i start to assign a values of abcd to a and then so on? I hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SqlAlchemy for this. Declare your ORM associated to you table in postgres. Then Start reading the excel using `csv_reader()` and at each row iteration you can assign the attributes to your ORM class and commit the transaction. In this case you don't need to use pandas.
[SQLAlchemy Docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/contents.html)

Comment: many thanks I will give it a try in couple of days and come back and update the solution.